# Pipedrive is it possible to send a new user notes deal etc to a specific pipeline?

Tags: pipedrive-api

My pipedrive deals are sorted in different pipeline that I can find easily with this kind of request :

> api.pipedrive.com/v1/pipelines/ID_PIPELINE?api_token=######

So what I was doing until now is to send data to

```
api.pipedrive.com/v1/organizations
api.pipedrive.com/v1/persons
api.pipedrive.com/v1/deals
api.pipedrive.com/v1/notes
```

And I send it to the user info@, which is link to a form type "contact-us"
What happen is that it goes by default to the primary pipeline, associated to info@

We created a second pipeline, also associated to info@ and when I am sending organizations / persons etc, **I am asked if it's possible to send it directly into the new pipeline instead of the "default one"**.

Like `api.pipedrive.com/v1/pipelines/ID_PIPELINE/organizations?api_token=######`

etc

At the moment I haven't find a clue about it, I wanted confirmation.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get it now. You can't add a deal straight to a Pipeline. But you can do so in Stage.

So what I did was get the specific Pipeline and then get the first Stage in its list and then use that Stage ID to add the Deal in.

PS. I'm going to improve this answer later. But basically that's the gist of how to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: Hey, sorry I never updated this question.
This is basically what I succeeded on doing, I get your answer.

It cost me a bit of time to found out, and thx for coming back at it JohnnyQ!

Comment: Thanks for your hint - I did a sequence of **Person**, then **Deal** (setting the stage_ID value, that matches the desired pipeline) and then I also needed an **Activity** for my data to store properly in PD.

Comment: You can find the the pipeline ID and stage ID in the postman collection:
https://pipedrive.readme.io/docs/run-pipedrive-api-in-postman-or-insomnia